# Create New Column In Mysql Database Row?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, insert

I have a database called form, in it a have a few columns.

```
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   | id     | title    | body      |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   1    |    A     |    10     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   1    |    B     |     3     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   2    |    A     |     9     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   2    |    c     |    40     |
```

Each row has an id representing a thread number. In the database when someone comments I have a php script that will pull the id from the database of the thread the user commented on and create a new column in that row within the database. Such as below:

```
   +--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
   | id     |  title   |   body    |  comment01  |
   +--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
   |   1    |    A     |    10     |     zyx     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+-------------+
   |   2    |    B     |     3     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
   |   3    |    A     |     9     |
   +--------+----------+-----------+
```

This way I will be able to extract the thread along with the comments and display them onto the page.

My question is how do I write the code to insert a new column in a thread id row when someone submits a new comment?

Comment: This is a very unusual design, generally you shouldn't manipulate your table (by adding columns). Make some research about relational tables and store your comments in a comments table where you will only manipulate the rows.

Comment: I totally agree with @sidyll , you should change your db design as user to comments is always one to many relation ...

Comment: To answer this; either you add another script to execute the insertion, or create a trigger.

Comment: @ sidyll I was thinking about inserting all comments in one column with comment01sometextcomment02sometext and then writing a php script that would grab the comment column, split each comment(num) and then repackage it into output on to the page. But then the dilemma comes into moving the comments along to the next page where they left off.